# Diablo like orbs in CSS3/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Hello is there any way to create something like diablo hp/mana orb?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAsDB.jpg
I mean transitions and overlaping circles.
I can use imagemagick, php, css3, html5, gd2, jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through the use of clever dropshadows and background-images:

```
#orb {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent url(http://www.contemporaryartsociety.org/media/uploads/2010/04/4286/20-poland-flag-jpg.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  color: #000;
  line-hieght: 100px;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

and a tiny bit of javascript:

```
//event that adds or substracts health
$(this).animate({'background-position-y': Math.random()*100 + "%"}, 500)
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/FhpVD/

[image]

Comment: thats's that what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

First the good news: you don't need to use imagemagick or gd2 for this.

You would start with a static image which would be the basic panel, including the empty orbs.

You would need to create this as a PNG image, so that you could make use of PNG's alpha channel transparency feature. Use this feature to make the glass effect on the orbs. You would create graphic this using  Photoshop (or Gimp, etc).

Once you have this graphic, and you have it positioned in the browser, it simply becomes a matter of layering the animated liquid effect behind this main graphic to create the effect of it being inside the orb. The glass effect produced by the alpha transparency will allow the liquid graphic to show through while still having the shine of the glass in the foreground.

To animate the liquid, use jQuery. I can't really go into much more detail, as I don't know how much of an animation you want. If you're going to go the whole way and have it bubbling, etc then you'll need to create the graphics for that as well.

But the important point, and the answer to your question, is that the main effect is achieved simply by layering the liquid behind the static foreground image.

Hope that helps.

Comment: but what to do if user have diferent resolution?

Comment: @KryQ - you didn't mention that in the question. You have a choice: Either do the above at high res and scale as required, or switch to a vector graphics format (ie SVG) instead of PNG. The basic technique of layering the images to achieve the effect will remain the same though.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this.

This is Pure CSS (no images)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/ASE3A/)

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="orb">
    The Orb
</a>
```

### CSS

```
.orb {
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 4.5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #666, 0 0 5px #999;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.orb:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #666, 0 0 50px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use SVG to create that. Take a look at Raphael JS library for cross browser graphics (http://raphaeljs.com/). There's a nice gradient effect (http://raphaeljs.com/ball.html) that you could use for those orbs.

Comment: it's nice library but i cant cut the top to the percetage :(

Comment: What do you mean? You can draw whatever you want with that library.

Answer (score 1):

Ok

First of all there is this gem:
http://raphaeljs.com/ball.html

All done by JS + SVG. Very close to Diablo 1 Health/Mana orbs (as far as I remember them)

For a simpler (not as visually accurate) solution use this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<circle cx="200" cy="200" r="150" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"  fill-opacity="0.6" />
<circle cx="140" cy="140" r="40" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke="red"  stroke-width="1" fill="white"  fill-opacity="0.4" /> 
</svg>
```

The filling effect can be achived by tweaking opacity (filling and stroke) via simple JS.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and cross browser compatible way might be to create a [sprite map](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/) of each percentage (100 small images with the "amount" filled in).